# PHP, Post unknown text field value, post to PHP file, and insert db as rows exist

Tags: php, html

I would like to insert something like purchase details. I have created two tables, purchases & purchase_items. So each purchase record can have more than 1 item.
I can insert one record into purchase table, but what i need is to insert rows into purchase with items added to the list.
Code is below

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `purchase` (`purchaseRef`, `vendorName`, `date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $reference, $vendorName, $date);

$reference  = $_POST["txtRef"];
$vendorName = $_POST["vendorName"];
$date       = date("Y-m-d");

if($stmt->execute()) {
   $lastID = $stmt->insert_id;

  // i want to add unlimited items, i wrote as follows

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

     $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `purchase_items` (`prchseID`, `ctgryNo`, `prdctID`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
     $stmt2->bind_param("sssss", $lastID, $ctgryID, $prdID, $qnty, $price);


     $param_name = "ctgryID";
     if(substr($key, 0, strlen($param_name)) == $param_name) {
         ctgryID=$value;
     }
     $param_name2 = "prdID";
     if(substr($key, 0, strlen($param_name2)) == $param_name2) {
         $prdID=$value;
     }
     $param_name3 = "qnty";
     if(substr($key, 0, strlen($param_name3)) == $param_name3) {
         $qnty=$value;
     }
     $param_name4 = "price";
         if(substr($key, 0, strlen($param_name4)) == $param_name4) {
         $price=$value;
     }

     if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
        echo 'error: '.$stmt2->error; exit();
     }
  }

}
```

Please help

Comment: And what is your problem here?

Comment: You don't need to execute `prepare()` more than once. Save yourself the overhead and move it outside the loop

Comment: This is a question and answer site.  If you don't actually ask a question, it is very unlikely that you will get an answer.

Comment: @Machavity, how? can you put example here

Comment: @u_mulder the problem is, it inserts rows into purchase_items tables more than what to expect. I only want to insert one row if $ctgryID, $prdID, $qnty are not blank/empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you iterate over `$_POST` when you don't have to.

Your `$_POST` already have all the values you need to insert and you can access them without `foreach`, just using `[]`:

```
$lastID = $stmt->insert_id;

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `purchase_items` (`prchseID`, `ctgryNo`, `prdctID`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt2->bind_param("sssss", 
    $lastID, 
    $_POST['ctgryID'],
    $_POST['prdID'],
    $_POST['qnty'], 
    $_POST['price']
);
if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
    echo 'error: '.$stmt2->error; exit();
}
```

**Update**: for more products with their prices you form `inputs` should use `[]` notation:

```
First product
<input type="text" name="ctgryID[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="prdID[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="qnty[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="" />
Second product
<input type="text" name="ctgryID[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="prdID[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="qnty[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="" />
Third product
<input type="text" name="ctgryID[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="prdID[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="qnty[]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="" />
And more
```

On server side you use `foreach` like this:

```
// print_r your `$_POST` and you'll see subarrays there

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `purchase_items` (`prchseID`, `ctgryNo`, `prdctID`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt2->bind_param("sssss", 
    $lastID, 
    $ctgryID,
    $prdID,
    $qnty, 
    $price
);
foreach ($_POST['ctgryID'] as $index => $value) {
    $ctgryID = $value;
    // here's the magic - use items from other 
    // $_POST subarrays with the same indexes
    $prdID = $_POST['prdID'][$index];
    $qnty = $_POST['qnty'][$index];
    $price = $_POST['price'][$index];

    if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
        echo 'error: '.$stmt2->error; exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think, that's if you have one textfield named as ctgryID for example, but how about if you have more products with their prices?

Comment: wow, that's works now, problem solved... i appreciate your help, thank you very much @u_mulder